# Tkinter how to disable scrolling when B1-Motion out of widget

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a program I'm making for my tablet that contains text widgets. I wanted to be able to scroll the text widgets simply by clicking and dragging them (since scrollbars are hard to use via touchscreen).

The issue happens though whenever you leave the text widget while still scrolling, you'll see the function I made fighting with how the Tkinter normally responds.

Normally if you drag out of a text widget it will scroll in that direction, but that's countering my function.

Apologies as I know this was worded poorly, but if you try the code and just try dragging it to scroll, you'll see my problem.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
last_y= None
root = Tk.Tk()
Text_widget= Tk.Text(root, height=20, width=30)
Text_widget.pack()
Text_widget.insert(Tk.END, "t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n")
Text_widget.config(state='disabled')


def tablet_drag_y(event):
    global last_y
    print 5
    if last_y==None:
        last_y=event.y_root
        event.widget.tag_remove(Tk.SEL, "1.0", Tk.END)
        return "break"
    movement= (event.y_root-last_y)
    event.widget.yview(Tk.SCROLL,-1*(movement), "pixels")
    last_y=event.y_root
    event.widget.tag_remove(Tk.SEL, "1.0", Tk.END)
    return "break"
Text_widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", tablet_drag_y)


Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe `bind('<Leave>', ...)`, `bind('<Enter>', ...)` let you change it when mouse leaves widget and go back (enter).

Comment: @furas you were correct, I just had to bind them to a function that just had `return "break"`.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

So just in case anyone else tries to do this I just want to officially answer, all credit goes to furas for the solution.

The issue was taking place in the `"<Enter>"` and `"<Leave>"` events, so I simply had to bind over them with a function that used `return "break"` to stop it from taking place.

Here is an updated version of my sample code with the solution implemented.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
last_y= None
root = Tk.Tk()
Text_widget= Tk.Text(root, height=20, width=30)
Text_widget.pack()
Text_widget.insert(Tk.END, "t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n\
    t\nh\ni\ns\n \na\n \nt\ne\ns\nt\n \nt\no\n \nf\ni\ng\nu\nr\ne\n \nt\nh\ni\ns\n \no\nu\nt\n")
Text_widget.config(state='disabled')


def tablet_drag_y(event):
    global last_y
    print 5
    if last_y==None:
        last_y=event.y_root
        event.widget.tag_remove(Tk.SEL, "1.0", Tk.END)
        return "break"
    movement= (event.y_root-last_y)
    event.widget.yview(Tk.SCROLL,-1*(movement), "pixels")
    last_y=event.y_root
    event.widget.tag_remove(Tk.SEL, "1.0", Tk.END)
    return "break"


def cancel_normal_scroll(event):
    return "break"


Text_widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", tablet_drag_y)
Text_widget.bind("<Enter>", cancel_normal_scroll)
Text_widget.bind("<Leave>", cancel_normal_scroll)


Tk.mainloop()
```